# Is it possible to dissavow all links from a top level domain (like .xyz)?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, negative-seo

Is it possible to disavow domain extensions? Like `.com` or `.net`?
Lately I noticed new spammers strategy instead of pointing many URLs to your server they point hundreds of domains from certain extensions like `.xyz`.

I just wonder, why not block all these links with one rule blocking extension like `domain:xyz`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment of writing this answer, the wildcards capability is not available in the Disavow tool.

Comment: I'm not sure the wild cards would be needed. This post from webmaster world says that when you disavow any domain all the subdomains get disavowed as well. https://www.webmasterworld.com/google/4809787.htm

Comment: A risked and included domain:xyz in dissavow file. I will update on results

Comment: How will you know if this works? Keep in mind that disavowed links will still appear in Google Search Console.